# Using Couchbase client in Python, how can I connect couchbase server with custom port?

Tags: python, port, couchbase

My Couchbase server is configured with a non-default port (for example):

```
web admin port : 31100
direct port : 31200
api port : 31221
memcached port : 31222
```

My connection string is `couchbase://localhost:31100/my_bucket` but it's not working.

How can I connect a Couchbase server in Python?

Comment: Do you need to use non-default ports? If so, why? Even if you can get the python client to work with a non-standard port, this may cause you some other headaches down the road.

Comment: In fact I have to connect already installed couchbase with non default port